# Script to Know the average mysql row size

Tags: mysql

I'm saving my raw logs using an mysql database.

How long can I store the data i need to know the average mysql row size.

who i do this?

Thanks

Comment: its a column in INFORMATION_SCHEM.TABLES. there you can found the AVG from a row and much more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Average row size for a given table (data only, excludes indexes):

```
select avg_row_length 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'your_schema'
and table_name = 'your_table'
```

Average row size (including indexes) for a given table:

```
select (data_length + index_length) / table_rows
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'your_schema'
and table_name = 'your_table'
```

Comment: it give me "849.5076" it's a size in bytes? 8KB per row?

Comment: Yes, that size is in bytes. So 850 bytes (less than 1 KB) per row.

Comment: This is very useful.  Try running it on a few tables, then optimize those tables and notice the drop in the number so you can have a calculable performance indicator.